# How to confirm apt-get confirmation during mysql-server installation

Tags: linux, bash, mysql

I am trying to write bash script that will install mysql-server-5.6
I want to ask user for password and then I will use it during installation mysql-server and some other configuration.

But my script is not working

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql_pass="pass"
mysql_pass_again="wrong pass"
while [ "$mysql_pass" != "$mysql_pass_again" ]
do
    read -s -p "Choose mysql root password: " mysql_pass
    echo -e "\n"
    read -s -p "Repeat mysql root password: " mysql_pass_again

    if [ "$mysql_pass" != "$mysql_pass_again" ]; then
        echo -e "\nPasswords do not match!"
    fi
done

echo -e "\nConfiguring mysql."

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $mysql_pass'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $mysql_pass_again'
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install mysql-server-5.6 >/dev/null
```

After I enter password nothing is happening. When I remove >/dev/null then I can see that mysql installer is informing me that passwords are incorrect and I need to press OK

However passwords are same if I echo them and also when installation is over I am able to connect to the mysql-server with password I entered during installation.

How can I tell apt-get to press OK for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with variable inside single quote:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $mysql_pass'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $mysql_pass_again'
```

When I change it to double qoutes "" it is working...